# Proving limits using $\epsilon, \delta$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> $Q$: show if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = + \infty$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$

Using $\epsilon, \delta$, what I found confusing is that when i have a limit that is equal to $\infty$, I don't know how to write that in $\epsilon, \delta$... what I mean by that is,

Let's say i have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = L$, then I know I can start this by saing,  for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ so that $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ with $0 < x-0 < \delta$

However, when limit is $\infty$, I have no idea how to write it in that form. Clearly, $|f(x)-\infty| < \epsilon$ is not right.. Could I get some help on this question? Thank you.

Comment: Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $\delta$ such that $0<x<\delta$ gives $f(x) > 1/\epsilon$

Comment: What's the definition of divergence to $\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an author writes:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \infty$

what they actually mean (since $\infty$ isn't actually a real number) is:

For ANY positive real number $M$ (no matter how large), there exists SOME $\delta > 0$ such that:

$0 < x < \delta \implies f(x) > M$.

Note this "formal" definition never mentions infinity, only real numbers, which is as it should be.

So let's use this to show that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{1}{f(x)} = 0$. To do that, we need to show that:

for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that when:

$0 < x < \delta$, we have $\left|\dfrac{1}{f(x)}\right| < \epsilon$.

Well, suppose we set $M = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$. We know that we CAN find a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) < M$ for all $x \in (0,\delta)$. For all of these same $x$'s, we have:

$\left|\dfrac{1}{f(x)}\right| = \dfrac{1}{f(x)} < \dfrac{1}{M} = \epsilon$, that is: we can use the same $\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

For all $M$ there is a $\delta$ such that if $0<x<\delta$, $f(x) > M$. This implies $\frac {1}{f(x)}<\frac{1}{M}$. Every $\epsilon > 0$, however small, can be expressed in the form $\frac{1}{M}$ for some $M$, and thus for the same $\delta$, $\frac {1}{f(x)} < \epsilon$.